# How to Paginate a MySql Ranking Query

Tags: mysql

I have the following ranking query working fine with a limit of 25 records per page, it shows 1st - 25th for the first 25 records, but when i go to the next page, the rank stays the same 1st - 25th when it should say 26th - 50th.

```
SELECT image, name, wins, losses, level, xp, wins AS W, losses AS L,
TRUNCATE(wins/IF(wins=0,1,wins+losses)*100,0) AS PCT, 
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
FROM teams p
, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
WHERE `console` = 3 AND `game` = 23 AND `laddertype` = 1 
ORDER BY xp DESC LIMIT " . mysql_real_escape_string($limit) . ", 25"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
FROM teams p
, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
```

you are resetting the value for @curRank to `0` every time you execute the query. Make this dynamic as well, adjust it according to your `LIMIT` clause.

On the second run change it to

```
FROM teams p
, (SELECT @curRank := 25) r
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to accept my answer by clicking the check, so others know the issue is solved. If you're interested, here's a quick tour on how this site works: http://dba.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I question the use of session variables for pagination purpose. What if current connection times out?

Comment: It's not for pagination purpose, it's for ranking. But sure, you could as well do it on application level.